# Cannot open PDF Document. The browser loads for a second or two but then nothing happens

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

Actually the issue is only with the PDF files in my asp.net application, is not opening (or) showing print print preview.

I click on a specific PDF Document and then click the print button. The browser loads for a second or two but then nothing happens. No document opens, nothing is printed, where as Microsoft Office documents (Word, Excel) will open up when I click the printer icon, which is normal. Documents with extension .txt and .jpg also behave normally. However there is a definite problem with PDFs.

On my machine (Windows 10) I tested IE 11 and Chrome and had these same exact issues on both browsers.

again i tested this on another machine (Windows 7 and IE 9) and experienced NONE of these issues. Everything worked as expected.

Comment: It's impossible to help without any information and the question is frankly very vague. What do you mean "I click on a specific PDF Document " and " The browser loads for a second " ? Does your *application* send a PDF to the browser? Where is *that* code? Or did you click on a URL? If the stored PDF is bad you should check the code that generates it. If the file isn't sent to the browser, check the code.

Comment: Anyway, just use your browser's develper tools or Fiddler to see what's going on. The Network tab will show your GET request and the results, eg the file if all goes OK, or the HTTP status code if the server fails. You can also use Fiddler to capture the traffic from your browser to the application. If you use Javascript to print, the Console will show any error messages

Comment: Yes, my application has list of documents . on selecting one pdf document and then click on print button it opens and shows print preview

Comment: What print button? *Your application's* print button? You can't force printing from a web server, so what does that button actually do? Run Javascript? Did you try debugging your Javascript? Did you hit F12 to see what's in the Console? We *really* can't guess what your code does

Comment: Its not obvious that this question has any relation to C# or .net in general.

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly set the content type header to be

```
"Content-type:application/pdf"
```

and the content disposition header to be?

```
"Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='somefile.pdf'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using some library for displaying pdf files - you need to reinstall it. Also such problem can be from ad blocker, try to disable it.